# How can I refactor my POST fetch function to be more async with Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux

I am fairly new to using react with redux especially when it comes to making certain functions async. Just curious about the steps someone would take to go about it. Below is my current POST function with some added Redux code.

```
createCheckList = (title) => {
if (!(title === '')) {
  fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/v1/check_lists', {
    method: 'POST', 
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify({ check_list: {title: title }})})
   .then((resp) => resp.json())
   .then(data => {
     this.props.dispatch(addCheckList(data.id, data.title))
     
    })
   .catch(error => console.log(error))
 }
```

}

Comment: Are we talking about `async` `await` ?

Comment: @Student Please provide more details on what you are trying to accomplish. Saying "more async" is not detailed enough. Maybe try honing in on a specific issue you are having with an example of your end goal.

Comment: @CommonKnowledge I want to take my create fetch request and turn it into an async action connected to Redux. For my todo app

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv yes

Comment: Maybe you need `redux-thunk` then.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv I already do, I specifically want to refactor my function above